# Нужно ли двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли в данном предложении двоеточие или можно обойтись запятой?

Перед специалистами был поставлен вопрос, как рационально использовать приобретенное оборудование и богатый производственный опыт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если двоеточие, то в конце вопрос.

Если запятая, то в конце точка.

Я бы поставил двоеточие, но и запятая не ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо! Не обратила внимание на это правило про вопросительный знак и точку в конце (косвенная речь).